# Reverse gap method in permutations and combinations

Tags: combinatorics

This is my second attempt at posting this question as last time I wasn't able to explain myself properly. But I have put it together in a completely different way this time.

There are $10$ distinct people sitting in a row in a fixed order and $4$ people are to be selected such that no two of them are consecutive. The way our sir solved this question is- the number of people left after selecting $4$ would be $(10-4)= 6$. Now taking six people, there are $7$ gaps around them. The $4$ people that were selected could have come from any $4$ of the $7$ gaps around these $6$ people (as these $4$ were non-consecutive). And the number of ways of selecting $4$ gaps out of $7$ is $\binom{7}{4}$. So the final answer is $\binom{7}{4}$. This is called 'reverse gap method' by our instructor.

Though it seems correct I can't quite feel comfortable with this logic. Can someone make this method clear?

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way: let positions $P_1, P_2, P_3$, and $P_4$ be chosen. Then we have $5$ gaps, $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ and $x_5$.
Then, we have: $$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=6$$ since $4$ positions have been chosen. Also, we have conditions $x_2>0, x_3>0, x_4>0$ and $x_1, x_5\geq 0$. So, adding $1$ each to $x_1, x_5$, and using the fact that number of natural solutions to $$y_1+y_2+y_3+...+y_r=n$$ is given by $\binom {n-1}{r-1}$, we get $\binom {7}{4}$ total ways to choose position. Since they are in fixed order, there is no need for any further calculation.

Comment: Yes I already know this method. But can you please tell if the method I mentioned is really feasible or not? Is it a correct way of thinking or is it a bit unclear? Because I feel that it is a bit unclear

Comment: What is unclear in my answer?

Comment: No not in your answer. I am saying, the method I wrote is unclear to me.

Comment: Yes, that is why I reformulated your teacher's logic to make it clearer...

Answer (score 0):

You may understand the method more easily in this way

$-P-P-P-P-P-P-$

With $P$ denoting people who have **not** been selected, the $4$ people who need to have a gap between them **must have come from** $4$ of the $7$ places marked $-$, hence $\binom74$

What your teacher explained was to take out $4$ people, and re-insert them into the gaps (dots) between the remaining

$. P.P. P. P. P. P. $

It is more usually called the **gap** method, but **reverse gap** method suits as well, the crux is that the methods are the same.

Comment: So what it effectively means is that we find the number of arrangements of 'non-selected' and 'selected' people and each arrangement represents a unique selection of 4 people right? Also thank you for the answer!

Comment: The crux is that although people are labeled (distinct), initially you treat them as unlabeled, and label them *after reinsertion* . Each such labeled sequence will thus be valid.

Comment: Yes. So initially we just find arrangements and the labels will come on their own.